# std::sort function is not sorting a vector, and I don't know why?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11, stl

I have written a code to implement the quicksort algorithm in c++, it is working but the std::sort() function is not working at all. Please explain to me why.

```
#include "header.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;
bool myfunction (int i,int j) { return (i<j); }
int Partition(vector<int>& A, int start, int end){
    int pivot_idx = (rand() % (end - start + 1)) + start;
    Xswap(A[pivot_idx], A[end]);
    int pivot = A[end];
    int P_index = start;
    for(int i=start; i < end; i++){
        if(A[i] <= pivot){
            Xswap(A[i], A[P_index]);
            P_index++;
        }
    }
    Xswap(A[P_index], A[end]);
    return P_index;
}

void Qsort(vector<int>& A, int start, int end){
    if(start < end){
        int middle = Partition(A, start, end);
        Qsort(A, start, middle-1);
        Qsort(A, middle+1, end);
    }
}

void quick_sort(void){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(n);
    //v.shrink_to_fit();
    
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        v[i] = rand() % 1000;
    
    /*for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    cout << endl << endl;*/
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now(); 
    
    //Qsort(v, 0, n-1);
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), myfunction);
    
    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now(); 
    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    cout << duration.count() << endl; 
}
```

If you want to know what output is being shown upon calling executing the snippet:
[image: Program output]

And if you want to see the contents of the header file:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <time.h>
void bble_sort(void);
void improved_bble_sort(void);
void quick_sort(void);
void ins_sort(void);
void Qsort(std::vector<int>& A, int start, int end);

template <typename T>
void Xswap(T& a, T& b);

#endif /* HEADER_H */
```

The vector in the output is completely unsorted; I have tried range-based for loop and iterators but nothing helped out. Please provide me some solutions or ideas, I'm completely confused.

Comment: `reserve` != `resize` Your vector is empty and you are accessing indices out of bounds.

Comment: Could you do a quick test? Before calling `sort`, test to see if `v.begin() == v.end()`?

Comment: Thanks @RetiredNinja, I replaced reserve with resize and the output became sorted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::vector::reserve` is a hint to the container to enable fewer reallocations. It doesn't actually make `v[5]` valid. Instead, use [`std::vector::resize()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize).

Comment: Yes, I just used `std::vector::resize()` and the problem resolved although `std::vector::reserve()` was doing the right job earlier; can you explain why?

Comment: It is more than a hint. It increases the capacity and *guarantees* that no pointers and iterators are invalidated, as long as everything fits into the reserved storage.

Comment: @SaswataMishra In my opinion the keypoint is that when passing the iterator pair begin(), end(), you are sorting an empty range. If you had used some kind of pointer access or indices earlier, it probably would have worked.

Comment: @MarkusMayr got it. Thank you for your help. :)